# Avalonia: fails to draw text to DrawingContext

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am developping a project using Avalonia.
I used as a workingBase for a graphical editor the following project which allows to draw lines and rectangles: https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/LineEditor

I am trying to write text in the `Avalonia.Media.DrawingContext` but I get `NullRefereceException` on calling `DrawingContext.DrawText` method (in debbuger, `formattedText._platformImpl` is null)

```
public void DrawText(DrawingContext dc, TextShape textShape)
{            
    var brush = new SolidColorBrush(ToColor(textShape.Stroke));
    var point1 = new Point(textShape.TopLeft.X, textShape.TopLeft.Y);
    var typeface = new Typeface("Arial");
    var formattedText = new FormattedText("Hello", typeface, 12, TextAlignment.Left, TextWrapping.NoWrap, Size.Infinity);
    dc.DrawText(brush, point1, formattedText );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you update the AvaloniaUI NuGet to the last version ? the version is old in this archived repo.

A quick search in a more recent example https://github.com/wieslawsoltes/Core2D and you can find DrawText occurences

Comment: Thanks. The problem wasn't present in the project where i imported the librairies. Maybe some framework issues